# Calling Rails Controller/action submit form from javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Here is my rails form in my view

```
<%= form_tag :action=> "valider" do %>
....
<%= submit_tag  "Valider", {:class => 'bouton', :onclick=>"valider_form()"} %>
...<% end %>
```

it called the valider_form javascript function and then the valider action of the controller to store data in database.

When user leaves the page with an non-empty form, we propose to store his data and we want to call the valider_form() javascript function and the valider action of the controller. We use the OnUnload javascript event, and it's easy to call the valider_form() javascript function. But, We don't know how to call in javascript the valider action, or simulate this post event.

Comment: I don't (yet) know enough about Rails to suggest this as an answer, but you should look into unobtrusive javascript drivers for rails.

Comment: Would you clarify the question? It is not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: The question is : How to call the valider action from javascript, or how to simulate the POST action of the form to this action ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an id to my form :

```
<%= form_tag  '/mon_equipe/valider', :id=>'equipe' do %>
```

In my javascript OnUnload event :

```
valider_form();
var form = document.getElementById("equipe");
form.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= form_tag url_for(:controller => 'controller_name', :action => :valider),
:remote => true do %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

The `:remote => true` option makes Rails submit the request dynamically with AJAX, calling the `:valider` method in the `'controller_name'` controller.